# Reading Servo Motor Status with PLC

Tags: servo, plc

I have a Panasonic A6 servo driver paired with Velocio Ace PLC. I am trying to read servo motor status. I followed the wiring diagram from the servo manual and connected the PLC digital input to Servo's digital output. However, I am not getting any reading. Below is my wiring diagram (Please ignore the DB9 stuff) :

[image: Wiring Diagram]

And here is the PLC digital input information:

[Ace Digital Input](http://aceautomation.eu/en/how-to-wire-digital-inputs-of-ace-plc/)

Here is the Panasonic A6 information

[Panasonic A6](https://industrial.panasonic.com/content/data/MT/PDF/manual/en/acs/minas-a6_manu-03_e.pdf)

Basically I need to read the S-RDY, INP, and ALM output from the driver. Can somebody please point me to the right direction?

Is this the right way of wiring it? If yes, what resistor value and size should I use?

[image: Possible Solution 1]

Comment: How about a data sheet link for the A6?

Answer (score 2):

The servo_ready, servo_alarm and positioning_complete outputs (S_RDY, ALM and INP lines) all are open collector outputs and therefore, to read them, you need pull-up resistors to Vcc on your PLC or use optos as shown below: -

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Can you please check the new wiring that I posted on my thread? Is it correct?

Comment: The pull-up resistor has to match the maximum input voltage levels for the PLC and 24 volts may be too high (but I can't be sure). You also need to choose a resistor value and that is something that careful reading of the A6 manual should tell you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several monitoring parameters in A6 servo drive. you have to link those parameters to the servo drive output channels and force those outputs (through their specific parameter) high to enable them sending information about their statuses. Also proper connection has to be made according to the manufacturer recommendation.